# Preventing / Validating the creation of child relationships before commit in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm trying to prevent my users from creating a relationship in a 'has many through' association with a record that doesn't belong to them.

My users have many locations through location_users. And their locations have many shops through location_shops. I have things protected currently with CanCan.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locationusers
  has_many :locations, :through => :locationusers  
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locationusers
  has_many :users, :through => :locationusers
  has_many :location_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :location_shops
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_shops
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_shops
end
```

And my cancan abilities

```
class Ability
  can [:manage], Shop, { :locationusers => {:user_id => user.id }}
  can [:manage], Location, { :locationusers => {:user_id => user.id }}
end
```

I can handle the creation / editing of locations via this setup and my users can only view / edit their own locations / shops.

The issue is the creation of these relationships.

If a user posts a location id which doesn't belong to them, the relationship is created regardless of whether they have permission to create it. Granted, they can't view this relationship but I need to prevent the creation in the first place.

Eg, a user with a single location with ID 314

```
>> User.last.locations.map(&:id)
=> [314]
```

When creating a new shop, if I alter the params posted:

```
:shop=>{:shop_name=>"Ye Old Shoppe", :location_ids => [1,2,3,314]}}
```

The above creates the relationship for four locations obviously. I need it to validate the location ids before the creation of the relationship.

The only thing I could come up with was adding before_add in the model:

```
class Location
  has_many :location_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :location_shops, :before_add => :check_location_ownership
end
```

Is this the correct way to go about it and if so, what should :check_location_ownership look like? Or, is there a better way to prevent the creation of the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you have done does make sense, there are 2 other ways I can think of.

1) Use `:conditions` option on the `has_many` relationship.

2) A custom validation method.

```
class Location
  has_many :location_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :location_shops
  validate :check_location_ownership
end
```

I would personally choose one of these 3 depending on the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would check_location_ownership have to do? Loop through the location_ids and make sure they all belong to the customer?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to access them through `self.shops.each(&:location_id)` (Since there are many!)

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Nice to get a reassuring answer :) S